# How to know if the router is internet access when connecting via wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

In windows when you are connecting via wireless it's tell you if their is internet access or no. in ubuntu i already connect to router but i don't know if the router is connect to internet or not?!

How to know if the router is connected to internet or not on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the terminal:

```
[[ $(ping -c4 google.com) ]] 2>~/ping_check.txt && echo "I have Internet" || echo "I don't have Internet"
```

For example:

```
$ [[ $(ping -c4 google.com) ]] 2>~/ping_check.txt && echo "I have Internet" || echo "I don't have Internet"
I have Internet
```

This uses the basic [`ping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ping.8.html) utility to send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to the remote host and get the ECHO_REPLY from the remote host (`google.com` in this case). If the host is UP (& if the firewall at both end allowing ICMP), you will get response back from the remote host, otherwise not.

This one-liner has an added advantage, the error message (STDERR) will be saved in a file in your homw directory `~/ping_check.txt`. If you don't have internet then you can check the file content and get an idea of the cause.

**EDIT:** Explanation of the command:

The command has three portions:

- `[[ $(ping -c4 google.com) ]] 2>~/ping_check.txt` will ping "google.com" 4 times and `2>~/ping_check.txt` will save any error message from the command in the file `~/ping_check.txt` so that you can check it later for potential problem. As we are only concerned about the success or failure of the command `ping -c4 google.com` we have put it inside the bash keyword `[[]]` so that it will return true `$? = 0` if the command succeeded or false `$? != 0` if the command failed.
- Then we have fairly simple command `echo "I have Internet"` which will just print `I have Internet` only if the previous returns success, this is ensured by `&&`. `&&` indicates that the next command will run only if the previous command (`ping`) is successful.
- the next part has `echo "I don't have Internet"` after `||`. `||` means the next command will be run only if the previous command is successful (`$? != 0`). So `I don't have Internet` will be printed only if the `ping` command returns failure.

Comment: Ping != "internet" as sometimes one can ping but not connect to servers due to DNS failure. Sure it is a good first step, but is it really any  better then opening firefox ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I have modified the answer..

Comment: Why don't you add a ping to 8.8.8.8 and tell the user if only dns isn't working?

Comment: @WilhelmErasmus: it was the [initial approach](http://askubuntu.com/posts/609713/revisions), the i have changed it to take DNS  into account.

Comment: @heemayl but why not have it tell you if dns is available and if internet is available?

Comment: Is their another solution?????

Comment: @AhmedHamad: Is this not working for you?

Comment: @heemayl: "ping -c4 google.com" worked, but i don't understand the other commands???

Comment: @AhmedHamad: Please check the edits in my answer..i have added the explanation....

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking into Network and Sharing Center on windows, which says if you have internet or not, as shown bellow in the screen. But this is not always a reliable method. For example , on my college network, some computers say there's no internet, and yet I can surf internet just fine.
[image]

heemayl alrady mentioned `ping` command which is the basic network testing tool on any system, windows or linux, and it is used in command line; the app for that is `cmd` on windows and `terminal` on ubuntu or any other linux distro, and macs. If you can `ping -c4 google.com` and get response, you have internet.

There's another method, graphical, using [`gnome-nettool`](http://go2linux.garron.me/gnome-nettool-linux-desktop-set-of-tools-for-network-analysis/), which is an app with network utilities all put together into graphical interface. Idea is the same, ping utility to test if you have response from internet; there's also traceroute, which will show if you can go past your router ip address to the internet or not.

Another way is through Unity Lenses and Scopes. Remember how when you type in dash when you search for some files, you get suggestions from amazon? well, that means those suggestions come from internet, right ? Personally, I have those disabled, so can't elaborate much on this.

But really, command line tools are far more reliable and much better and many linux users will strongly recommend you use those

Comment: on the signal icon on taskbar their sometimes a yellow triangle that tell you "no internet access"